Competition Bot Elevation
I’m working on a VEX V5 robotics project and could use some advice on designing an elevation mechanism for our robot. We need to tackle a specific challenge this year, which involves elevating our bot through multiple planes. The elevation requirements are outlined in this year's game manual https://content.vexrobotics.com/docs/2024-2025/v5rc-high-stakes/HighStakes-1.0.pdf. (pages 13, 14, and 22)
Requirements:
We are trying to elevate the robot up three rungs, and we cannot skip any of them. Ideally, we would also like to score a ring in a goal at the top of the ladder that is positioned in one corner of the tower. This goal has a guard, which requires there to be a downward force to score the ring. In addition to this, it would need to fit on either side of the robot, as the center space is occupied by our intake system. There is also only a 10-second period to elevate so the faster the method the better.
We’ve considered a few ideas and attempted some solutions, but we’re looking for more insights and suggestions. So far we have considered having some sort of passive hang on the first level and then having an arm on either side which would each grab the second and third levels in order. This is plausible but my team does not know how we would score in the goal at the top afterward.
Has anyone faced similar challenges or have any innovative ideas on how to achieve this?
Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
